# Is it generally safe that people can view your js files

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

Is it generally safe that everyone can access your javascript files? I know that you should have important algorithms on the server side and call them with AJAX through javascript, but even then, others can find out what AJAX calls you are making, and what information you are sending, and they then may be able to modify your content to force your site to end some information

For example, say an AJAX call takes the content of an input file `<input type="hidden" id="example" value="very important information" />` and sends it over. Now the visitor knows this is what the ajax is using, so they can edit the content (through Firebug for instance), before initiating the ajax call.

Is there a way/good practice to fix these kind of issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe for users to read your Javascript code.

The contents of AJAX calls are not hidden from the user. If your application can be exploited by a user performing AJAX calls, it is insecure! Your application should perform all appropriate access checks on the server side for every call, just like it performs similar checks for requests based on a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you are talking about any public website or application it should not be good practice but in applications it should not have a problem, because we can use strong algorithms to authenticate and we will have only authenticated users to login every time so we consider hackers are not there to change values from hidden fields.
**Session** is one of the best way to keep important information on server and only handle other data from client side.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need to edit content, you can just fire an Ajax call in console for whatever, or send any request.

It's the job of server side script to provide security protection, not Javascript. No "fix", ever.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to NEVER TRUST what a user sends. A well-coded application will have safeguards against any invalid data. It doesn't matter if you use AJAX or a simple post of a form - a user can still find out what that browser sends to the server. So - best practice - use server-side logics to validate data and protect yourself from such situations.